# 2007 to 2010 Migration Errors

Tags: migration

I thought I had removed solutions prior to migrating the content DB but still get the following Health Anaylzer messages on the 2010 Web server:

[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [ab314113-075d-4aaa-bca4-8906758c8d2d]. The feature with Id ab314113-075d-4aaa-bca4-8906758c8d2d is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [472aa5bb-c6d5-4f9e-8539-ca64a62bb7c5]. The feature with Id 472aa5bb-c6d5-4f9e-8539-ca64a62bb7c5 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\OEMAlert\OEMAlert\OEMAlert.webpart] is referenced [1] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [97ded2bd-da4b-1c8c-87bb-446d7d77c313] is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.

[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [2795e39b-dbab-5d0e-7ae8-8cace0abae2b] is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.

Is there a set of steps that I can follow to make sure that there are no remnants of Features/solutions referenced before migrating (attaching DB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the original 2007 farm you can run the `stsadm -o preupgradecheck`

You should be able to verify if they are missing in the original farm, or installed there.  If they are installed, than you can remove the feature / solution thru normal methods.  If they are missing there as well, you have to go in and remove the refrences.

You can use `stsadm -o enumallwebs -includewebparts > enumwebparts.txt` to get a dump of all the webpart references and sites they are located on.  Go thru the pages from the report and delete the referenced webparts.  Use the ?content=1 on the page and remove any Error and closed webparts.

You can do the same thing for you missing setup files `stsadm -o enumallwebs -includesetupfiles >enumsetupfiles.txt`

You only have a couple of each reference to track down, so you should be able to manually remove them fairly quickly.

**EDIT**

If you delete them via the UI you need to go in and delete them from the End User and Site Collection Recycle bins or they will still show as an error.

Also be sure to have the October 2009 CU which has the most up to date rules for the preupgradechecker.

Comment: Very informative answer. I didn't have the Oct '09 cumulative updates to the preupgradecheck tool installed - do you think this would have helped - the only error I saw was because the 2007 version was on 32 bit server (to be expected)? Also, could you outline the differences between the STSADM preupgradecheck and Powershell sp-testcontentdatabase commands?

Comment: Updated post to reflect you should be running Oct 09 CU to get the latest rules.  PreUpgradeCheck and TestContentDB are nearly identicle, the difference is one will check what you have NOW in 2007, the other allows you to test a DB against a 2010 webapp and discover what's missing without attaching it to the farm.  The latter is good to let you know if you missed migrating customizations to the new farm before you upgrade. Ideally most of your work would have happened wiht the preupgradechecker on 2007.