# 2007 to 2010 Migration Error

Tags: migration

I have performed a database attach migration and, as expected, received errors in the log like:

> [STSADM] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [1/16/2013 8:46:44 AM]:
>   Found a missing feature Id = [d56f0d2d-0107-424d-aa0d-7120329a23e6]
>
> [STSADM] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [1/16/2013 8:46:45 AM]:
>   The feature with Id d56f0d2d-0107-424d-aa0d-7120329a23e6 is referenced
>   in the database [WSS_Content], 
>             but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which
>   contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

I removed the features from the database using (for 3 offending Features):

```
DELETE FROM WSS_Content.dbo.Features WHERE FeatureId = 'd56f0d2d-0107-424d-aa0d-7120329a23e6'
```

I'm still getting the generic File Not Found error page and don't know what to do next?

Comment: You already asked about this in your question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43271/2007-to-2010-migration-errors

Comment: The answer to that focused on Web Parts - If I had an answer I wouldn't be posting the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you have to uninstall the feature, but also deactivate the feature. I wouldn't touch SQL statement for all SharePoint environments, as Microsoft will slap you in the face. Here's a good article on how to remove those annoying "missing feature" errors:

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=371

Excerpt:

> First you can uninstall the feature (it has to be there to uninstall
>   it, we’ll see that in a second.)
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm -help uninstallfeature
>
> stsadm.exe -o uninstallfeature
>              {-filename  |
>               -name  |
>               -id }
>              [-force]
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id
>   bbe9def7-2fe9-a0b1-d712-aa128c837ebe
>
> Feature with Id 'bbe9def7-2fe9-a0b1-d712-aa128c837ebe' is not
>   installed in this farm. The feature was not uninstalled. Looks like by
>   doing a search, this feature is related to the community kit blog.
>
> If the feature is not installed on the farm, and you want to force
>   remove the feature you can run stsadm to deactivate the feature.  More
>   context to this error on William Wolfe’s blog.
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm -help deactivatefeature
>
> stsadm.exe -o deactivatefeature
>              {-filename  |
>               -name  |
>               -id }
>              [-url ]
>              [-force]
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\BIN>STSADM -o deactivatefeature -id
>   bbe9def7-2fe9-a0b1-d712-aa128c837ebe
>
> The feature with Id 'bbe9def7-2fe9-a0b1-d712-aa128c837ebe' is not
>   currently installed. Use 'force' to deactivate it at this scope.

Comment: I deactivated the three features but still getting generic error page.

Comment: and you uninstalled them?

Comment: Yes, still on luck. Not seeing an upgrade log second time I attached the  2007 DB.

Answer (score 0):

AHHH!!! You directly queried the database!

The correct way to resolve this would be to determine what installed feature is on your farm with that Guid. Then deactivate and uninstall the feature before detaching / reattaching the database again. Or you can install the same feature on your 2010 site if it's compatible and leave the feature activated on the source farm.

Directly interacting with the content database will cause your SharePoint installation to be unsupported by MSFT.